# Scrapy Login Authentication Isn't Working

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Hi I'm working with scrapy to log into some random website. I followed the tutorials on scrapy and it doesn't seem to be working. When i try it, i notice that the "isAuthenticated": False. And the html body i return doesn't contain everything that the actual website does. I'm not sure what the issue is. I thought it was the CSRFtoken but after research i found that scrapy should handle that. Here is the code below. Any Suggestions?

```
  import scrapy
  import sys
  from scrapy import Spider
  from scrapy import Request

  class IvanaSpider(Spider):
     name = 'ivanaSpider'

     def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.FormRequest(
              'https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/',
              formdata={'username': 'username', 'password': 'password',
                       'form_build_id': 'form - v14V92zFkSSVFSerfvWyH1WEUoxrV2khjfhAETJZydk',
                       'form_id': 'account_api_form',
                       'op': 'Sign in'
              },
              callback=self.after_login)]

     def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "It's recommended that you log in" in response.body:
           print "------------------------------------------"
           self.logger.error("Login failed")
           return

        # continue scraping with authenticated session...
        for line in response.xpath('//body').extract():
           print line.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
```

Comment: I added the form_id stuff in an attempt to fix this, but did nothing

Answer (score 0):

To login to website, you will need to use **FormRequest** but for some website, i.e. ***bitbucket*** in your example,

they use predefined form attributes like CSRFtoken, session info and other tokens which can only be used from the previous page user have visited

In such cases, one can use [FormRequest.from_response](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=formrequest#scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response) method of scrapy which collect all pre-defined params from the response and post them as a formdata

```
# For example 
import scrapy
import sys
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy import Request

class IvanaSpider(Spider):
    name = 'ivanaSpider'
    start_urls = (
        'https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response=response,
            formdata={"username": "<your username>",
                      "password": "<your password>"},
            #formname="login",apparently there are many socal login forms so select one based on xpath ( form id)
            formxpath=".//form[@id='aid-login-form']",
            callback=self.after_login,
            dont_click=True,

        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "It's recommended that you log in" in response.body:
            print "------------------------------------------"
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return

        # continue scraping with authenticated session...
        for line in response.xpath('//body').extract():
            print line.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
```

Comment: ah so you need to have already accessed the website to have access to special authentication tokens. So since parse is called after the spider calls a request on the start URL, it will essentially have access to the special authentication token from the response. At this point we just don't overwrite the formdata, and it will already be there. Do i have this right? I just wanna makes sure i understand this in my head.

Comment: After trying this, it seems it takes me to the "sign in with google option" rather than the regular login. Any suggestions?

Comment: After looking at the data. i assume that because clickdta is not set, it defaults to the first clickable button which is the google login button. Thanks!

Comment: check the updated code , and yes scrapy will collect all default form parameter values from response and submit, Also any formdata which you will set, will override default value that it will collect from response

Comment: So changing the clickdata could be a solution, but because the button's here arn't named that isn't possible. The only solution is to edit the formxpath? Also why is the "dont_click=True" there? When i remove it, there doesn't seem to be any difference.

Also the html body i get is quite different from the actual page. Is it this just a result of crawling vs the actual response to a human?

Comment: no click data will not solve iy, since there are multiple forms , so you wil need to select right form, i.e. Facebook or google or native email-password..... click data is useful when there is only one. form on page but based on the event attribute server will act differently i.e. next page , prev page , relode, no of items in given page..etc